# Is there any generalized version of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, orthonormal

all. I want to ask your opinion about the following question:

Let $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ be a matrix having full column-rank, and let $\{ \mathbf{u}_{1}, \cdots, \mathbf{u}_{r} \}$ be the set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $\{ \mathbf{A} \mathbf{u}_{1}, \cdots, \mathbf{A} \mathbf{u}_{r} \}$ is orthonormal. Then, does the following inequality hold true? Here, $\mathbf{A}^{T}$ denotes the transpose of $\mathbf{A}$.

\begin{align}
\underset{i=1}{\overset{r}{\sum}} \| \mathbf{A}^{T} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{u}_{i} \|_{2}^{2}
&\ge \frac{r^{2}}{\| \underset{i=1}{\overset{r}{\sum}} \mathbf{u}_{i} \|_{2}^{2}}
\end{align}

When $r=1$, then the above inequality clearly holds true by the well-known Cauchy-Schwarz inequality ($\| \mathbf{A}^{T} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{u}_{1} \|_{2} \cdot \| \mathbf{u}_{1} \|_{2} \ge \langle \mathbf{A}^{T} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{u}_{1}, \mathbf{u}_{1} \rangle = \| \mathbf{A} \mathbf{u}_{1} \|_{2}^{2} = 1$).

How about the case for $r \neq 1$?

Comment: If you just want my opinion, I'd say it's fun to read.

Comment: Hint: If $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_r, q_1, q_2, \ldots, q_r$ are any $2r$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $\left(\sum_{i=1}^r \left|\left|p_i\right|\right|_2^2\right) \left(\sum_{i=1}^r \left|\left|q_i\right|\right|_2^2\right) \geq \left(\sum_{i=1}^r \left< p_i, q_i\right> \right)^2$. This is a kind of vectorial version of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and follows easily from the usual Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Now, apply this inequality to $p_i = \mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{A u}_i$ and $q_i = \sum_{j=1}^r \mathbf{u}_j$.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but in this way, we only get $\underset{i=1}{\overset{r}{\sum}} \| \mathbf{A}^{T} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{u}_{i} \|_{2}^{2} \ge \frac{r}{\| \underset{i=1}{\overset{r}{\sum}} \mathbf{u}_{i} \|_{2}^{2}}$.

Comment: Ah, you're right.